# Add Event Handler from String

Tags: c#

Hi all I have a button and I know it has a "`Click`" event.
How Can I add this event with "Click" and Delegate? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define helper method:

```
public static void AddEventHandler(object obj, string eventName, Delegate handler)
{
    if(obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
    if(eventName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("eventName");
    if(handler == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("handler");

    var type = obj.GetType();
    var evt = type.GetEvent(eventName);
    if(evt == null) throw new ArgumentException(
        string.Format("Event '{0}' is not defined by type '{1}'", eventName, type.Name));

    evt.AddEventHandler(obj, handler);
}
```

and use it:

```
AddEventHandler(yourButton, "Click", yourHandlerDelegate);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the .cs file related to your form (Web Form, Win Form)::

```
// This will handle the event for the button named bntSubmit
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Code to handle click event
}
```

Generally speaking, most people (but not all) use the `<controlid>_<event>` naming convention for event handlers.  Like btnSumbit_Click for the OnClick event for a button with an id of btnSubmit.

For ASP.NET, you'll need to set the buttons OnClick attribute in the markup (.aspx file) (double-clicking on the form in the designer will also generate the stub):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
```

In Win Forms, double-clicking the button on the designer is the quickest way to generate the method stub.

I haven't worked much in MVC or WPF, but I'd imagine the process is similar, and the method signatures are the same.